# Filtering table by multiple columns and refresh filter's values

Tags: jquery, filter, datatables-1.10, yadcf

I'm using jquery.dataTables and yadcf and cannot find solution on how to restrict filters in multiple columns by selecting one.

For example: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

If I select name from the "**Name**" filter, then I still get all the possibilities in the "**Positions**" filter.

What I want to get is e.g. based on the position selected, only names in the filter options are available which has this position.

Same in the opposite way, if I select name, then only available options in the position filter should be those, which name has associated.

Any advice, please?

Answer (score 1):

`{cumulative_filtering: true}` ... is the answer